# How to use an handler(created before the looper) in a looper inside thread

Tags: android

hi mate in all tutorial or example the handler used in a looper is created inside the looper example:

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

but if a create the handler before the thread, at example

```
public Handler mHandler=new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };
```

is possible associate him at the thread in run() method in a looper or i must create him only in run method inside the looper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor in `Handler` basically looks like this:

```
public Handler() {
    ....
    mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
    if (mLooper == null) {
       // throws an exception
    }
    ....
}
```

The field, `mLooper` is a package-private `final` field - and, of course, there's no setter available for you to change it later on.

In short, the `Handler()` constructor will associate itself with `Looper.myLooper()`, there are other constructors that allow you to pass the `Looper` - but these would also require you to create the `Looper` prior to creating your `Handler`.